# Rails asset pipeline and javascript files - maintaining line breaks to aid debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs

I recently migrated from [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) to the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).  Other than a few teething issues, everything has been working well.

However, I recently started getting some script errors in production, and realised that it's near on impossible for me to debug them.  I had previously configured Jammit to retain linebreaks, but otherwise remove all white space in the javascript files.  This was to ensure that should I see a runtime error, I would be able to locate the offending line and hopefully figure out what the problem is.  With the Rails Asset Pipeline, and the default :uglifier compressor, it appears all whitespace is removed including line breaks, and as such my script errors do not tell me where in the code the problem was.

Does anyone know anyway to configure the Rails Asset Pipeline to retain line breaks so that code can be debugged?

Matt

Answer (score 10):

Set in you `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

and running `rake assets:precompile` won't uglify your assets.

**UPD:**

So-called compression means (among other stuff): remove line breaks and comments. 
But if you want to obfuscate your variables and save some readability then use:

```
# in production.rb
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:beautify => true) if defined? Uglifier
```

Here see for more options: https://github.com/lautis/uglifier.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am after.  I do want to compress the files, I just want to keep line breaks so that code is split over multiple lines.

Comment: See UPD if you want to make your code both ugly and readable ;)

Comment: tried this but getting an `uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::Uglifier` error.  I realise it's because Uglifier is not loaded in my gem set, but I don't want to include Uglifier in my production Gem set as I compile my assets locally and push the compiled assets to production.  Any ideas on how to get around this issue so that Uglifier is only loaded when compiling assets?

Comment: @MatthewO'Riordan `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:beautify => true) if defined? Uglifier`. Reflected in the answer.

Comment: @jdoe, this will only run if it is defined, and it clearly isnt from his error, thus making his attempt to pass specific arguments impotent