# Rails asset pipeline strips out plugin copyrights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have some `vendor` files in my application that contain copyright information that needs to be visible if someone were to look at the source file. But when asset pipeline runs, it strips all of that out. Is there anyway to not remove the copyright information?

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297564/rails-asset-pipeline-and-javascript-files-maintaining-line-breaks-to-aid-debug), you might get the desired output if you are using [Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier), and use the option `Uglifer.new(output: {beautify: true})` (note that this hash is slightly different due to, I'm assuming, a difference in versions). I cannot test this at the moment which is why I'm not putting this as an answer, but let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify `uglifier` option to leave copyright comments.

Replace `config.assets.js_compressor` in your `production.rb` to this:

```
if defined? Uglifier
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(
    output: {
      comments: :copyright
    }
  )
end
```

[Here](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) you can find list of all `uglifier` options.

P.S. Don't forget to remove precompiled assets before precompile them again with new options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're putting all the copyright info in a comment, no. Precompiling the assets minimizes your Javascript and CSS, which strips out comments.